# Wanting to determine the area of self intersecting polygon in Java

Tags: java, swing

I have a series of points with x and y coordinates
They represent polygons.

polygon1 is an arraylist of points (1,2,3,4,5)
polygon2 is an arraylist of points (5,6,7,8,9,10), This one is a self intersecting polygon

Some polygons are self intersecting i.e figure 8 shape such as polygon 2

Is it possible to find the area of the polygons which are self intersecting
by using swing methods such as Path2D or using java API methods

I saw in the Java 7 api there is AREA class and it looks like it could be used
to get area for each polygon area making up the self intersecting polygon though not sure how or if that could be done?

Answer (score 1):

Area is actually since java 1.2

You can use

`area1.intersect(area2).getPathIterator(...)`

to get a PathIterator from which you can determine the area

Comment: Thanks, is the area1 the first part of the figure 8 polygon (Polygon2) and area2 the second half of the figure 8 polygon (Polygon2) above? i.e is 5,6,7 one part of the self intersecting polygon and the ,8, 9, 10 the other half of the self intersecting polygon. I am not sure from my polygons would which be area1 and area2

Comment: General question. Does the Polygon class in the Java 7 API allow the creation of self intersecting polygons. I have point lists each representing a polygon. Some point lists represent self intersecting polygons, other lists represent normal polygons. None of the polygons geometry (lists) overlap, so I am not sure if  Java AREA class is relevant for me to get the area of each polygon especially those that are self intersecting polygon?